# Does own node run faster than Infura?

Tags: ethereum, geth, parity

Will I feel the big difference if I will raise own node on a powerful server with good internet 100Mbps+ ???﻿

Did someone experiment with the speed of own node and Infura?

Answer (score 1):

The infura throttles the speed of accessing their API, it is actually much faster in terms of response time using your own hosted Ethereum node than using theres. The caveat is that hosting on Amazon AWS or others is not free, considering the storage requirement and network traffic for a full Ethereum node.

Answer (score -2):

Personal machine will not be able to match infura. They have very high powered server with superb internet bandwidth. If you go to there site, see the numbers..

Can you transfer 2.5 PetaByte of data in 1 month with you 100MBPs internet? NO.

[image]

Comment: You do not need to transfer 2.5PB out because you are not serving all the MetaMask users in the world.